# Compiling a libusb example program

Tags: 11.10, usb, g++

I recently installed the library libusb by doing this:

> sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev

I have a directory with examples that looks like this:

```
penguin@penguin-Satellite-A505:~/Downloads/libusb-1.0.0/examples$ ls -la
total 124
drwxrwxrwx 3 penguin penguin 4096 2011-10-23 11:38 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 penguin penguin 4096 2011-10-23 11:38 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 penguin penguin 4096 2011-10-23 11:38 .deps
-rw-r--r-- 1 penguin penguin 10781 2008-08-22 22:57 dpfp.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 penguin penguin 11644 2008-06-24 21:00 dpfp_threaded.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 penguin penguin 1643 2008-11-03 15:13 lsusb.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 penguin penguin 15923 2011-10-23 11:38 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 penguin penguin 356 2008-11-20 08:24 Makefile.am
-rw-r--r-- 1 penguin penguin 16380 2008-12-13 12:07 Makefile.in
penguin@penguin-Satellite-A505:~/Downloads/libusb-1.0.0/examples$
```

I am trying to compile lsusb.c. Would anyone know how to do it? My OS is Ubuntu 11.1.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in looking at the list of files installed by the libusb-1.0-1-dev package at pakages.ubuntu.com. The source code should read like this:

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

Also the -L switch must be used with the compiler so the libraries can be located at the location installed.

Answer (score 0):

There are [makefiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) in the directory, so try just running `make`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Ubuntu 11.04 installs with libusb-1.0, but 11.10 installs with libusb-0.1.  Does anyone happen to know more about the apparent backrevving of the lib?

I tried a few times (unsuccessfully) to manually build and install libusb-1.0 to Ubuntu 11.10, but wasn't able to.  Haven't exactly tried the procedure above.